# What to do when there are doubts about wuzu?

Tags: wudu, waswasa

I face a lot of doubts about wuzu that my wuzu is broken. I am really frustrated with these doubts. What can I do to save myself from these doubts ?

Comment: You should do wuzu again.

Comment: I would wonder if i haven't seen many of this questions. What is really new in yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have *waswasa* regarding passing of wind: You shouldn't presume based on sensation, but should only redo wudu when you have clearly heard it or smelt it:

> Narrated `Abbad bin Tamim: My uncle asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) about
>   a person who imagined to have passed wind during the prayer. Allah'
>   Apostle replied: "**He should not leave his prayers unless he hears
>   sound or smells something**."
>
> <sub>— [Saheeh Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/3)</sub>
>
> Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: If any one of
>   you has pain in his abdomen, but is doubtful whether or not anything
>   has issued from him, be should not leave the mosque **unless he hears a
>   sound or perceives a smell**.
>
> <sub>— [Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/3/126)</sub>

Regarding waswasa regarding something coming from the genitals, the prescribed method is to sprinkle water over them so that one knows they are intentionally moist:

> It was narrated from Hakam bin Sufyan Ath-Thawri that: He saw the
>   Messenger of Allah perform ablution **then take a handful of water and
>   sprinkle it over his private area** [to remove any doubts about urine
>   drippings.]
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1254600) and [Sunan Nisai](https://sunnah.com/urn/1001350)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Just Ignore them its called waswas its a evil thought that shaytaan gives a whisper to everyone to not do good things like praying namaaz and as you said wudu

Comment: Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).