# Consistent farting. Breaks wudu?

Tags: wudu

Let's say I did wudu for 6:40. Isha at 7:10. I pray maghrib but I feel like I consistently fart. Can I still pray maghrib and isha on the wudu I made, if my farts are consistent?

Comment: Do you really consistently fart or is it possible that it is your imagination? If it is real then is it a one time occurrence (e.g. due to overeating) or is it a disease?. If it is a disease then have you consulted a doctor to determine if it is incontinence?

Comment: Essentially, I don't hear a sound or smell anything, but I am pretty sure that something is coming out. Hence I say I consistently fart. I don't think its a disease. Not my imagination.

Comment: See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40099/

Comment: To be honest no. Its not if there is doubt with wudu. I know that my wudu is broken, but if its constant, must I repeat wudu constantly?

Answer (score 1):

You should get it checked out by a doctor before assuming anything. I suffer from incontinence and the ruling for that is to do a fresh wudu for each namaz but it has to be done at the time of the prayer. But I would still get it checked out first before following anything.