# Feeling like Madhiy has been released, and constantly checking for it

Tags: salat

I have a dirty thought. Sometimes I feel like something has been released but when I check nothing is there. Sometimes I don’t feel anything but there is something there. I can’t ignore it. I’m constantly checking and it takes a lot of time just to do wudu and pray. The discharge I see could also be regular vaginal discharge but I don’t know how to tell, especially with these thoughts randomly coming in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when there are doubts about wuzu?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40099/what-to-do-when-there-are-doubts-about-wuzu)

Answer (score 0):

> I was one who Madhi (urethral discharge) flowed readily and asked
> Miqdad (his slave) to ask the Prophet (ﷺ) about it. He (the Prophet)
> said:“One should perform Wudu (ablution) in this case”. [Agreed upon
> and this is Al-Bukhari’s version].
>
> https://sunnah.com/bulugh:69

So when you want to pray and doubt if there is madhiy, just take ablution before you pray.